# Who is this King Bhavya who lived on the banks of Indus?

Tags: rig-veda, rishi, sacrifice, kings

**[Rig Veda Book 1 Hymn 126](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01126.htm)** is dedicated to a king who has given a lot of gifts to a certain Kakshivan in a sacrifice:

> 1 WITH wisdom I present these lively praises of Bhāvya dweller on the bank of Sindhu;
>   For he, unconquered King, desiring glory, hath furnished me a thousand sacrifices.
>
> 2 A hundred necklets from the King, beseeching, a hundred gift-steeds I at once accepted;
>   Of the lord's cows a thousand, I Kakṣīvān. His deathless glory hath he spread to heaven.
>
> 3 Horses of dusky colour stood beside me, ten chariots, Svanaya's gift, with mares to draw them.
>   Kine numbering sixty thousand followed after. Kakṣīvān gained them when the days were closing.
>
> 4 Forty bay horses of the ten cars' master before a thousand lead the long procession.
>   Reeling in joy Kakṣīvān's sons and Pajra's have grounded the coursers decked with pearly trappings.
>
> 5 An earlier gift for you have I accepted eight cows, good milkers, and three harnessed horses,
>   Pajras, who with your wains with your great kinsman, like troops of subjects, have been fain for glory.

**I want to know if there are more details or any other stories about this king who lived on the banks of the Indus in any commentary or any other scripture?**

Comment: Bhava or Bhavayavya was a king who lived on the banks of the Indus in RV 1.126. His son was  Savanya or Bhavya . Do you want answer of  king **Bhava , Bhavayavya** OR **Savanya ,  Bhavya** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhava_(king)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am herewith providing more  details of the  story of King Bhavya or  King Swanaya mentioned  in Rig-Veda mandala  1- Sukta 126. The story is present in both this as well as in previous sukta  i.e.  RV. 1.125.

King Bhava or Bhavayavya was a king who lived on the banks of the Indus,whose son was [**King Swanya Or Bhavya.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhava_(king))

The Rishi of the Sukta 1.125 is Kakshivan Dharghatamas and Devata is Swanay Danastuti.

The Rishi of the Sukta 1.126 is Kakshivan Dharghatamas , Swanaya Bhavaya & Romasha and the Devata is  Swanaya Bhavya .

Both Sukta 1.125 and 126 is mentioning the story. And the story is mentioned by [**Sayanacharya in his   Rig-Veda bhashya**](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.41621/2015.41621.Rig-veda-Sanhita--Vol-2#page/n45/mode/2up)  translated by H.H.Wilson.

---

Now let's see what is the story mentioned by Sayana.

**Brief of the story** - Kakshivat  is a Vedic sage  . He was the son of Dirghatamas and Usij.  He was also called Pajriya, because he was of the race of Pajra,  means strong. He is the seer of  hymns RV. 1.125 -126  he praises  on the liberality of King Swanaya. 
Kakshivat, finished his vedic  study, took leave of his guru and left  home. As he journeyed night came and   he fell asleep by the roadside. In the morning he was awaken by king Swanaya, who, was impressed by his appearance, treated him in friendly way  and took him home. After knowing  Kakshivat's worthiness, he offered  his ten daughters to Kakshivat in marriage. The king presented Kakshivat at the same time with a hundred nishkas of gold, a hundred horses, a hundred bulls, a thousand and sixty cows, and eleven chariots, one for each of his ten wives, and one for himself, each drawn by four horses. In return Kakshivat praise King Swanaya in a Vedic hymn.

---

**Sayana's introduction  Of  Hymn RV.1.125 -:**

> This Hymn is supposed to be recited by Kakshivat , in the
>   acknow-ledgment of the liberality of Raja Swanaya ,whose gift is
>   therefore considered as the divinity of the hymn , or the object
>   addressed.

Sayana's details about the story mentioned in RV. 1.125 .

> The legend which is cited by Sayana and which is told to the like
>   purport in the "Niti-Manjari" relates that Kakshivat , having finished
>   his course of study and  Kakshivat, took leave of his preceptor , was journeying homewards , when
>   night came on , and he fell asleep by the road-side: early in the
>   morning , Raja Swanaya , the son of Bhavayavya , attended by his
>   retinue, came to the spot , and disturbed the Brahmanas slumbers :
>   upon his starting up , the Raja accosted him with great cordiality ,
>   and being struck by his personal appearance , determined ,if he was
>   suitable rank and birth , to give him his daughters in marriage .
>   After ascertaining his fitness , he took Kakshivat home with him and
>   there married him to his ten daughters , presenting him at the same
>   time with a hundred nishkas of gold , a hundred horses , a hundred
>   bulls , one thousand and sixty cows , and eleven chariots , one for 
>   each of his wives  and one for  himself , each  drawn by four horses.
>   With this present Kakshivat returned home , and placed them atthe
>   disposal of his father Dirghatamas , reciting this Hymn in praise of
>   Swanaya.

---

And here is what he says about Bhavya in [**RV.1.126**](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.41621/2015.41621.Rig-veda-Sanhita--Vol-2#page/n49/mode/2up)

> Bhavya is here identified  evidently with Swanaya his son.

So  Bhavya or Swanaya was the son of Bhava or Bhavayavya. His full name  King Swanaya  Bhawayabya . Romasha was said to be the daughter of Brihaspati and the wife of   King Swanaya or Bhavya.  .

Comment: Little jumble of words but hope that you will get it. This is just details of the story and not much about king Bhavya. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details was wondering why he is being praised so much! I would love to find out more about his genealogy or family to know a tentative time frame of his existence.

Comment: Yes , King Bhavya was generous king , and curiously DanaStuti (praise of charity) is  devata. His liberality was seen by the Rishi Dirghatamas as divinity.

Comment: Yes ,I will try to find more about him ,but initial search results  are  not encouraging. May be there is no mention  of either Swanaya or Bhavya in Mahabharata or Puranas. But will try my best.

Comment: This rishi is Kashivan right not Dirghatamas. I think he was the son of Dirghatamas and has some verses in Rigveda too.

Comment: Yes , I know ,but look at the sayanas story (in block quote) , Kakshivat presented the gifts to Dirghatamas his father and he recited. But may be the rishi is both Kakshivat and Dirghatamas. Both are seers. will look into it.

Comment: Hmm maybe he is being referred to with both names as a patronymic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81759/discussion-between-swiftpushkar-and-dr-vineet-aggarwal).

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal - The name actually is Kakshivan Dharghatamas (दैर्घ्यतमस) i.e. son of Dhirghatama.The pronunciation is different.( दीर्घ and दैर्घ्य )

Comment: Exactly what i just wrote in the chat. Well that's sorted now lets focus on the king :)

Comment: On a verge of getting another 25+ reps

Comment: @RakeshJoshi - LOL , You also could have earned it if you answered the questions .Besides ,reputation Is the fuel ,that drives SE networks. I pretty much like you comments these days.They make me smile .